# Context.SaveChanges() Doesn't work until application restarts

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, mvvm

I work on some hotel application. I have one ListView with some columns and one column is CheckBox column. When I click on that CheckBox the selected item is removed from ListView.
Also when I click on that CheckBox i call a method from WCF service which doesn't work quite well. In database I have a table (tblStay) with a boolean column named "IsFinished". I need that column to be set as "True" after CheckBox is clicked. Now this is strange: after i put on breakpoint and checked if everything works well, it actually do works well. The field "IsFinished" has the value of "True", but in my db it is still set as false. Then I restart the application and do the same thing again, and then it is saved as "True" in my db. Also this is not always the case. Sometimes it's saved correctly but in most cases it does not work propertly. Here is my code:

**ViewModel:**

```
    private ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest mainGuest;
    public ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest MainGuest  //bound as selected item in ListView
    {
        get
        {
            return mainGuest;
        }
        set
        {
            mainGuest = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainGuest");
        }
    }

private ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest> mainGuests;
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.tblStayGuest> MainGuests    //bound as items source in ListView 
    {
        get
        {
            return mainGuests;
        }
        set
        {
            mainGuests = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainGuests");
        }
    }


private ICommand _FinishedStay;  // this command is bound to my CheckBox column in listview
    public ICommand FinishedStay
    {
        get
        {
            if (_FinishedStay == null)
            {
                _FinishedStay = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ServiceReference1.Service1Client wcf = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
                        MainGuest.IsMainGuest = false;
                        wcf.FinishedStay(MainGuest);

                        if (MainGuest.tblStay.IsFinished == true)
                        {                                
                            MainGuests.Remove(MainGuest);
                        }
                        wcf.Close();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }
            return _FinishedStay;
        }
    }
```

**WCF:**

```
  bool IService1.FinishedStay(tblStayGuest mainGuest)
    {
        try
        {
            context = new HotelBaseEntities();

            //tblStayGuest stGuest = (from stg in context.tblStayGuests where stg.StayGuestID == mainGuest.StayGuestID select stg).FirstOrDefault();
            tblStay stay = (from st in context.tblStays where st.StayID == mainGuest.StayID select st).FirstOrDefault();
            tblGuest guest = (from g in context.tblGuests where g.GuestID == mainGuest.GuestID select g).FirstOrDefault();
            tblBooking book = (from b in context.tblBookings where b.GuestID == mainGuest.GuestID select b).FirstOrDefault();
            tblRoom room = (from r in context.tblRooms where r.RoomID == mainGuest.tblStay.RoomID select r).FirstOrDefault();


            guest.IsCheckedOut = true;
            mainGuest.IsMainGuest = false;              
            stay.IsFinished = true;
            book.IsActive = false;
            book.IsCanceled = true;
            room.RoomStatus = false;
            context.SaveChanges();

            var contactEntry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(stay);
            contactEntry.ChangeState(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);


            List<tblStayGuest> GuestsInRoom = (from gs in context.tblStayGuests where gs.StayID == mainGuest.StayID select gs).ToList();
            foreach (tblStayGuest stayG in GuestsInRoom)
            {
                tblGuest guestToCheck = (from gtc in context.tblGuests where gtc.GuestID == stayG.GuestID select gtc).FirstOrDefault();
                guestToCheck.IsCheckedOut = true;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }


            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.StackTrace.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `context.Entry(stay).State = EntityState.Added;`, use only one `context.SaveChanges();` and instanciate your context outside the function?

Comment: I can't use that in my version of EF so i did this:
 var contactEntry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(stay);
            contactEntry.ChangeState(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

And about context.SaveChanges(); I used it twice when I was trying to solve the problem so forgot to delete it here. Still Doesn't work

Comment: And I'm not adding new record here to my db, i just updating already existing record.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? There is no transaction in your code, so it seems that when you call `context.SaveChanges()` the object is not marked as changed so EF doesn't change your database. If you create and a new instance does it work (e.g. `context.tblStays.Add(aNewInstance);`?